# Third-party authentification library for the MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, angularjs, authentication, mongodb, mean

I have already created a website using [MEAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MEAN_(software_bundle)).

Now, I want to add an authentication page, from where we can sign in with Google, GitHub, Facebook and LinkedIn, or sign up with an email, like follows.

Does anyone know if there is any existing code that we could use to build this? This is a quite common need, it would be astonishing if one has to build everything from scratch.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Scotch](https://scotch.io/) has a series on ["Easy Node Authentication"](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local), specifically using [Passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org/).

Passport has over 300 different authentication "strategies", including:

- [Google](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth)
- [GitHub](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-github)
- [Facebook](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook)
- [LinkedIn](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-linkedin)
- [Twitter](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-twitter)

For your standalone email authentication, [OAuth2orize](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize) can be used with Passport authentication strategies and application-specific route handlers to assemble a server that implements the OAuth 2.0 protocol.

Comment: Do you have example of it being used in the MEAN stack?

Comment: That tutorial in Scotch is a little bit outdated, and I cannot make it run.